# Implementation of stl map in c++ using class of values

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have to develop stl map in which key is integer where value associated with key is 5 tuple.
having integer data types only.

```
e.g key=1
value=(2,3,4,5,6)
key=2
value=(1,2,3,4,5)
```

and so on.
how i can implement it for insert and search operation.

mean how to map single key value to tuple of 5 values.
how to accomplish it?

Comment: Concatenate multiple containers? Like `std::map<std::vector<T>>` Or `multimap` from boost

Comment: If the map's value is of fixed size, I would recommend `std::map<int, std::array<int, 5> >`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your data means I would go for a different approach.
If your values logically belong together, that is if they only make sense in combination, then I would simply store them in a common data structure and store this data structure in a map. For this purpose a class, struct or container might suit your needs. Again it depends on your context what is the best choice.
If your values exist in isolation and the only connection between them is that they share the same key, then I would use [std::multimap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/?kw=multimap).

Comment: but i have to use all the 5 values at a time to identify the object.so i want to use map only,can i use class of values?

Comment: As I said, if your 5 values belong together, then you can store them in one structure. This structure can be of different forms. You didn't provide enough information on what you want to do so I cannot tell you what would be the best option in your case, but a class would be *one* possible option, yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to `C++11`, you can make use of `std::tuple` (or boost´s tuple), which I believe is the best fit data structure to your case. See the snippet below and see if it fits:

```
#include<tuple>
#include<map>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdexcept>

typedef std::tuple<int, int, int, int, int > fiveIntTuple; 

void insert(std::map<int,  fiveIntTuple>& values,  
            int key, int a, int b, int c, int d, int e){

    values[key] = std::make_tuple(a,b,c,d,e);
}

fiveIntTuple search(const std::map<int, fiveIntTuple >& values, int key ){
    return values.at(key);
}

void print(const std::map<int, fiveIntTuple >& values, int key){
    try{
        fiveIntTuple t;

        t = search(values, key);

        std::cout << "For key  == " << key << " got:  " 
        << std::get<0>(t) << "," 
        << std::get<1>(t) << "," 
        << std::get<2>(t) << "," 
        << std::get<3>(t) << "," 
        << std::get<4>(t) << std::endl;         

    }catch(const std::out_of_range&){
        std::cerr << "For key " << key << " ... not found" << std::endl; 
    }
}

int main(){
    std::map<int, fiveIntTuple > my_values;
    insert(my_values, 1, 2,3,4,5,6);
    insert(my_values, 2, 1,2,3,4,5);

    print(my_values, 1);
    print(my_values, 2);
    print(my_values, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Executing this snippet you must get:

```
For key  == 1 got:  2,3,4,5,6
For key  == 2 got:  1,2,3,4,5
For key 3 ... not found
```

Comment: But my server is g++ with 4.4.6 version....where i cant update it to 4.7.How i can include it with g++ 4.4.6

Comment: @user3168101 Could you use boost?